# When should I use "of which"?

Tags: relative-clauses, pied-piping

If I want to say two things, can I always combine them by “of which”? Is there any rule for that?

For example, if I want to say

> 1. 3d objects with and without jump edges produced by the intersection of straight lines.
> 2. 3d objects represented by a method A.

then, could the combined sentence be as below? Does my “of which” work correctly?

> 3d objects with and without jump edges of which produced by the intersection of straight lines represented by a method A.

Comment: Your proposed "combined" sentence is definitely meaningless/ungrammatical. But the question as it stands gives us no clue as to what you actually *want* to say, and it's quite obvious the only existing answer hasn't helped you. You need to edit the question to explain what you are trying to express. Also - is it actually relevant that your sentence #1 includes two different kinds of 3d objects? Is it relevant *how* the "jump edges" are produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you are misunderstanding the construction *of which*. *Which* here is a relative pronoun, and *of which* is a prepositional phrase with *of* as its head and *which* is the object. It is used with a quantifier to speak about something relating to its *antecedent*—the object or set of objects referred to by *which*.

I think<sup>✲</sup> that you are trying to combine the following facts:

1. [There are] 3D objects.
2. Some **of them** have ‘jump edges’.
3. The ‘jump edges’ are produced by the intersection of straight lines.
4. Others **of them** do not have ‘jump edges’.
5. All **of them** are represented by Method A.

You have elected to express your first four facts this way:

> A. [There are] 3D objects, with and without jump edges produced by the intersection of straight lines.

There is nothing wrong with this. But you might instead use *of which* and express the same facts either of these ways:

> B. [There are] 3D objects, some of which have jump edges produced by the intersection of straight lines and others of which do not.
>
> C. [There are] 3D objects, of which some have jump edges produced by the intersection of straight lines and others do not.

Observe how *of which* is used here:

- *Of which* is a prepositional phrase modifying *some* and *others*, just as *of them* is a prepositional phrase in facts 2 and 4.
- *Which* is a relative pronoun whose *antecedent* (the thing it refers to) is *objects*, just as *them* is a *demonstrative pronoun* whose antecedent is *objects*.
- *Of which* is used here with nouns acting as the subject of the following clauses: *some .. have edges ... and ... others ... do not.* . In this case it is used with *some* and *others*, but it might be used with anything which relates to the *objects* using the preposition *of*: *the contours of which*, *the colors of which*, *the names of which*

So now you see how you may use *of which* to add fact 5 to your sentence: *which* still refers to *objects* and you use *all* as the quantifier:

> D. [There are] 3D objects, with and without jump edges produced by the intersection of straight lines, ***all of which*** are represented by Method

---

<sup>✲</sup> If I have misunderstood any of your facts, please let me know and I will rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

"Of which" is used when you have a group of items, and you want to explain a certain characteristic of some (NOT ALL) of the group.

I know that might be hard to understand; let me give you a quick example:

Police are looking for a bald man.
They know he is within a crowd of 100 people, where 10 are bald.

Then the crowd contains 100 people, of which 10 match the description.

See? You specify a characteristic that doesn't pertain to the entire group.

Comment: You can also say *all of which*, in which case it *does* pertain to the entire group.

Comment: @DarkLightA: thank you for the explanation. I think I got what u said. So i guess, my sentence should be like this; "3d objects of which produce by the intersection of straight lines represent by the method A."

Comment: No problem; I'm glad it helped! For future reference, please use 'you' rather than 'u.' It just looks 150 times more professional.

Comment: @niro That example doesn't work.  The usage DarkLightA describes has to paired with a quantity: "of which *only one*" "of which *several*" "*all* of which" "of which *thirteen*" "*thirteen* of which"